# Why css `width:30%` work incorrect

Tags: css, width

**Thank for the answers, clearly I made a horrible mistake on math...**

Here is my code.

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>

<style>
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
</style>
```

After rendered, the width of `p` is `90px` instead of `100px`. I tested on the newest version of Chrome,Safari,Opera,Firefox. All got the same result. Why?
[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qseKc/1/)

Comment: I can't believe the `width` tag actually has 10 followers.  Is there some secret organization somewhere that is inherently concerned with questions regarding the breadth of things? :(

Comment: @Moo-Juice - you apparently just scared 10% of the width followers away. Only 9 now. Well done!

Comment: 30% of 300px is 90px, not 100px. 30% != 1/3

Comment: Rolled back for future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 3):

The width is actually 96px.

```
.3 * 320 = 96
```

You will get close to what you want with `33.33`

http://jsfiddle.net/s2Lbm/

Answer (score 2):

because 100/3 = 33.33333 so set width to 33.33%